# Issue with resizing column with jQuery DataTables and colResizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on a responsive table and encountered an issue when using both DataTables and colResizable on my table.

Ideally I want to resize columns so both th and td is resized at the same time.

When I enable sScrollY to get a scrollbar for tbody the column resizing only works for the td element, and no longer for th like it did prior to enabling sScrollY (See JSFiddle)

Code:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
     sDom: "Rlfrtip"
    //,sScrollY: "680px" // When enabling this, resizing only works for td, not for th.
    ,bPaginate: false
    ,bInfo: false
    ,initComplete: function(settings) { 
    $('#example').colResizable({liveDrag:true});
}});
```

JSFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/eLm6ugp7/103/

Edit:
It seems this has been a problem for other people also, as seen in this related discussion: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26786/basic-column-resizing-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be an issue related to compatibility between two plugins.

I created an issue on GitHub regarding this problem. More information and suggestions can be found here:
https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable/issues/74